# content types vs. paragraphes types + taxonomy

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I have quite a complex content structure and found the paragraphs module (in combination with taxonomies) can be very powerful for creating complex compound fields and dynamically reusing existing content types.

Example: 1 content type "equipment" tagged with a term from a taxonomy "mobility devices" (terms: car, aircraft, bike...) and with different fields of paragraphs types representing the different attributes for each of the devices. This way I'd only use the car_paragraphs_field if the equipment is tagged as a car and leave the other paragraphs fields blank. This in contrast of having multiple different content types "car", "bike"...

I'm wondering whether this a reasonable approach in terms of later displaying data in views, storing data to the DB, internal Drupal complexity/load when having let's say 100 different paragraphs types and only using 1 for each new content (i.e. leaving many paragraphs types fields blank), instead of having one separate content type for each.

Comment: Proper content modeling is important. I wouldn't go full boat on Paragraphs, but use them for 'display pieces' on content. If it is important and pertinent to the content type, use structured data.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with structured data?

Comment: Actual fields. Not paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think this is a good use case for paragraphs. I don't see any benefit of having only a single content (node) type, you are just moving comeplexity from nodes to paragraphs.

I think the key here is to carefully plan and reuse fields across entities. If your car equipment and your plane equipment both have a weight attribute, reuse the same field (or to be more precise: reuse the field storage), so e.g. you can use it to as filter in a shared view for both equipment types.

Comment: Ok so that'd mean having separate content types for each "equipment" but reusing fields/field storage wherever possible. I was only hesitant to do it this way as this might results in many many content types...

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but if your dataset is that big, you either have a lot of node types, or you have a lot of paragraph types. As long as using paragraphs doesn't save you from creating additional entity types, be it either additional paragraph types or additional node types, I can't see any benefit in using Paragraphs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes, taxonomy terms and paragraphs are all different types of entities.
Each entity type has unique properties that make it better suited for different use cases and content types.

Here’s a breakdown of the most important Drupal terminology you need to know to structure your content:

**Node:** A page of content is a node, accessible via its own URL

**Taxonomy terms:** Used to categorize other content, taxonomy terms live in a hierarchy. They can be used to filter content and create unique landing pages.

**Paragraphs:** Content that lives within other content and doesn’t need a dedicated URL is a paragraph.

You can read more here : https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/structuring-content-drupal-8